# if condition is not working in jframe

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, jframe

This is my code for login page for an desktop application.
in this the if condition in the action listner is not working properly.
it always shows wrong password

```
    final String n1 = textField.getText();      
    lblJph.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 34));       
    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("User Name");       
    lblNewLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);       
    passwordField = new JPasswordField();       
    final String pass = passwordField.getText();    

    //final char[] n3 = passwordField.getPassword();
    //final char[] n2 = {'a','d','m','i','n'};
    //final boolean check = n3.equals(n2);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Password");      
    JLabel label = new JLabel("");      
    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Submit");       

    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {             
            if(n1.equals("admin") &&  pass.equals("sales")){                    
            SALES j=new SALES();                
            j.setVisible(true);
            dispose();              
            } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong Password / Username");
            textField.setText("");
            passwordField.setText("");
            textField.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You are ignoring `CASE` of string, use `equalsIgnoreCase()` if that is the case...

Comment: btw. `"sales".equals(pass)` can't cause a NullPointerException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to read the passwordfield and username field inside your actionlistener

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        String n1 = textField.getText();
        String pass = passwordField.getText();

        if(n1.equals("admin") &&  pass.equals("sales")){

        SALES j=new SALES();

        j.setVisible(true);
        dispose();

        }
        else {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong Password / Username");
        textField.setText("");
        passwordField.setText("");
        textField.requestFocus();
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `String pass = passwordField.getText();` **inside** the actionListener. pass is never getting an updated value

Same goes for n1

Answer (score 0):

try this to retrieve the password from passwordfield **INSIDE THE ACTION LISTENER** in the following way :

```
char pas[]=passwd.getPassword();
String pass=new String(pas);
```

then check

```
pass.equals("sales");
```